# Clustering a word and its abbreviation together in python

Tags: python, text, text-analysis, abbreviation

I have a list of strings in Python.

For example,

['FD for 5000','RD', 'Fixed Deposit for 10000', 'RD for 1000', 'Recurring deposit for 1000']

The input need not be the same. The strings in the list could be in any order and the list could be of any length.

I would like to put the strings with the word and its abbreviation together into seperate lists.

Expected Output:
{['FD for 5000', 'Fixed Deposit for 10000'],
['RD','RD for 1000', 'Recurring deposit for 1000']}

I am trying to actually cluster user entered comments together. Some users may enter the text in abbreviated form while others may enter it in full form. So in order to group similar comments together, I need a generic way.

Would appreciate any possible solution.

Comment: Clustering (unsupervised statistical methods) *cannot* do this.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I understand intuitively why this is true, but is there a more formal argument? Could you point my to some reading material?

Comment: Abbreviating is not part of a clustering.

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to do that. For example:

1. All odd elements of your list are abbreviations. You can get them using list comprehension:

   ```
   [a for (a,b) in zip(a,range(10)) if b % 2 == 1]
   ```

   Similarly, non-abbreviations:

   ```
   [a for (a,b) in zip(a,range(10)) if b % 2 == 0]
   ```
2. Use `list[start:end:step]` with `step = 2`.

Comment: Hi masteromusica, Thank you for your answer, but I just provided the list as an example. The strings within the list could be in any order and the list could be of any size. It would help if you could provide a more generic way to cluster the texts. Let me edit my question.

Comment: @sofibijusenthil unless you add more details about properties of those strings, I can't help you

Comment: I am trying to actually use the above to cluster user entered comments together. Some users may enter the text in abbreviated form while others may enter it in full form. So in order to group similar comments together, I need a generic way.

Comment: find a common *thing* all abbreviations share (length less than X maybe?) and use list comprehension with an if statement. That's as generic as it'll get